# Is there a way to fix the "Encountered two children with the same key" error on react native when sending gifted chat messages to firestore?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-gifted-chat

I had set up a react native group chat application using gifted chat ui with firestore database but I keep getting this error once I ran the application.

> Warning: Encountered two children with the same key

[image]
The error seems to be coming from the getMessages method

```
  parseMsgsFromFirestore = snapshot => {
    const { id: _id } = snapshot;
    const { text, user } = snapshot.doc.data();
    const stampInSeconds = snapshot.doc.data().timestamp.seconds;
    const timestamp = new Date(stampInSeconds * 1000);
    const message = {
      _id,
      timestamp,
      text,
      user
    };
    return message;
  };

  getMessages = callback => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('messages')
      .orderBy('timestamp')
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const changes = snapshot.docChanges();
        // TODO: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key {Error occurs in about 5 minutes and then persists}
        changes.map(change => callback(this.parseMsgsFromFirestore(change)));
      });
  };

  sendMessages = messages => {
    // sending only specific properties to firestore
    for (let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      const { text, user } = messages[i];
      const message = {
        text,
        user,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
      };
      this.concat(message);
    }
  };

  concat = message => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('messages')
      .add(message);
  };
```

In my Chat.js file, I call that method on the componentDidMount method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import fireStoreDB from '../database/FirestoreDB';

export default class Chat extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.getParam('name')
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fireStoreDB.getMessages(message =>
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message)
      }))
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    fireStoreDB.signUserOut();
    fireStoreDB.snapOff();
  }

  get user() {
    return {
      // gifted chat user props
      name: this.props.navigation.getParam('name'),
      _id: fireStoreDB.uid
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GiftedChat
        messages={this.state.messages}
        onSend={fireStoreDB.sendMessages}
        user={this.user}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

All my message keys are unique in the database, except they're all are from the same user id.
[image: All my keys are unique in the database.]

Comment: What are you using for the `key` prop when looping over your messages? can you show that part of your render function?

Comment: @azium I added the render function and haven't used any key props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your data is missing unique `_id` fields. As you can see from this line of code https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/master/src/MessageContainer.tsx#L281

```
key: item._id,
```

That's the `key` it's complaining about. Make sure your messages have an `_id` field and make sure they are unique.

Right now have you have `User._id` but the top level message should also have its own `_id`.

```
const { text, user } = messages[i]; // Does this have _id ??
```

Comment: This was the message's id  `const { id: _id } = snapshot;` but it was undefined because it was missing the doc method call `const _id = snapshot.doc.id;` That fixed my issue.

Comment: You need a client-side _id, not id